# MonoTouch css styling

Tags: css, xamarin.ios

I am new to monotouch and wanted to know if there is a simple way to implement css styling in any of the types of views/viewcontrollers? I have read about WebViews, worked with UIViewControllers, but I want to build an app that is basic styling for now that I can update later with css styling from a design organization. Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5 has some limited support for global styling.  Miguel has a [post that explains how](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Oct-14.html) to use it in MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough there was a project on Kickstarter.com which ended up getting funded which allows you to use CSS3 to style iOS and soon Android apps. It actaully works really well.
[Pixate.com](http://www.pixate.com)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take a look at it sometime!